# Enforced time off and statutory holidays - Ontario

Tags: work-time, canada

My company is planning a plant shut down from June 29 2018 to July 6 2018. During this period there is a statutory holiday.

How does it work if forced time off and statutory holidays fall within the same time period?

Comment: There is no way of telling without knowing your location and the details of your labor agreement. In most situations paid holidays are not mandated by law, but are simply part of the labor agreement/contract.

Comment: Ontario Canada is my location

Answer (score 1):

By Ontario law you should be paid according the following rule:

> The amount of public holiday pay to which an employee is entitled is all of the regular wages earned by the employee in the four work weeks before the work week with the public holiday plus all of the vacation pay payable to the employee with respect to the four work weeks before the work week with the public holiday, divided by 20

There are exceptions for specific industries as outlined in the link below but in general your fear that you would lose a paid day off doesn't align with the law.

Edit: Slight correction, if you have an unpaid day off on June 29th that will result in a 5% reduction on your stat pay.

https://www.ontario.ca/document/your-guide-employment-standards-act/public-holidays#section-5

Comment: Technically you don't have be paid for a statutory holiday if you don't work the day before it, or you may get paid somewhat less. In reality most employers just pay everyone for the stat. I only ever used that "add up the days and divide by 20" for people who worked varying number of hours per day so that "a day's pay" was a hard thing to determine.